# using generic interfaces in MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I am developing an application which is MEF enabled. There is a core library project which works as a glue and implements :

```
 CompositionContainer cc = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

 cc.ComposeParts(this);
```

I have declared all [Import] parts in this core library such below:

```
 [Import(typeof(IHost))]
        // The imported host form
        public IHost Host
        { get; set; }

   [Import(typeof(ILightStudents<?>))]
   public ILightStudents<?> StudentsAPI  { get; set; }
```

There in so problem in implementing IHost or other interfaces in other library projects which has [export] attribute, but problem here is that I have declared  ILightStudents like this:

```
public interface ILightStudents<T> where T:class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Students();

        T GetStudent(long id);

    }
```

But as you saw in previous code, I put '?' mark in import part. As you know the purpose of generic methods is that you can implement them by which ever class or type you want. And here I want to implement ILightStudents in other library project with my proper type, but I cant leave [import] part without specifying the type.

Would you help me please ?

**Edited**:

I almost could solve the problem by using dynamic type binding.

Comment: The only place where your <?> can come form I can think of is a type parameter on the class that houses the StudentsAPI property. Since this class is not something that your plugin knows about (is it?) there is now way for plugin to export implementation for it. I'd like to know what functionality are you envisioning on the export side?

Comment: There are two methods implemented in export side. first one returns a list of students, second one get one student`s id and return her/his info. The core library which gathers all dll files for getting exports, does not have any idea of what the type of '?' could be.
I also used 'object' type for '?', but it did not work and gave me this error: "The export 'StudentsModule.DAL.StudentsAPI (ContractName="SabteNamCore.Interfaces.ILightStudents")' is not assignable to type 'SabteNamCore.Interfaces.ILightStudents'."

Comment: Generics are not supported in MEF for .NET 4.0 .
It has been added to MEF 2 in .NET 4.5 so either wait for it or get the previews.

Comment: This explains why it doesn't work - http://codebetter.com/glennblock/2009/03/21/why-doesn-t-mef-support-open-generics-for-exports-because-mef-is-not-type-based/

Answer (score 2):

Use either:

- The code in MefContrib or
- MEF 2 preview.

This feature was added in both - it will be included in .NET 4.5.

Comment: is there any helpful link or sample ?!

Answer (score 2):

i copied the answer from another thread here a few days ago:

Try

```
[Export(typeof(IService<>))]
```

To get a generic type definition from the typeof operator, you omit type arguments. For types with more than one type parameter, use commas to indicate the "arity" of the type. For example:

```
typeof(List<>)              // not: typeof(List<T>)
typeof(IDictionary<,>)      // not: typeof(IDictionary<K, V>)
```

Comment: what about the 
[Import(typeof(ILightStudents<>))]
        public ILightStudents<?> StudentsAPI { get; set; }

Comment: i did not see your whole code, but your property should get the type whether with or without MEF. Eg. public ILightStudents<MyClass> StudentsAPI { get; set; }

Comment: The problem here is that the type has located in other library, which current library (the one contains import) has no idea of what it is.